# CSS not refreshing - now deleted, not cached, inexistent - and still loading? How? Why?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress website and I have styles loaded from two stylesheets - original style.css and style-custom.css for additional style.

Unfortunately whatever I do, the styles do not refresh. I already tried to press <kbd>Shift+F5</kbd> without success.

I've purged the server and browser cache entirely several times (even though it's actually permanently turned off via WP Engine). I've removed appended `?ver` numbers to force the update of the file content.

Right now I've even deleted the file and it is still loading in the browser! Even worse - it's loading in all browsers that I have not even ever used on the damn site.

I don't know what else to do. The file is gone and the cache has been purged.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely some sort of caching mechanism still. Are you developing on your own server? If you try to refresh on somebody else's computer are they able to see the file?

If yes - then you need to contact the servers' administrator, or you hosting provider with clarification.

You should be developing your websites locally though, and once they are ready publish them on the web.

Comment: No, it's all on WP Engine. I've removed all caching from the server, disabled WP cache, deleted advanced-cache.php, opened the goddamn site on all browsers I never used and it still loads the #@%#@%@ file. Although the guy at WPE tells me it shows him 404 for the CSS file link.

So it seems it could be the browser - but how and why, if I removed everything from my history ten times over, browsed incognito on Chrome and Firefox (never used) and still NOT A THING CHANGES.

Comment: Then the cashing has to be somewhere between you and the server. Are you on a student network or something and whoever is providing your internet is caching the websites locally?

Comment: Unlikely, I have my own home connection.

Comment: You may be onto something here, since my phone shows the file is gone, but my other laptop (working on local connection) still shows it's there.

Comment: And nope, reseting router didn't work either. I'm going insane now, I've wasted several hours on this crap and I still can't get anything to change...

Comment: But it is a network issue, because when I switch to mobile files load correctly. I'm going to find the guilty one and strangle them.

Comment: And nothing works - I can still load a file that was deleted days ago, despite repeated clearing of the server and browser cache, and using 3 different devices on two connections. It's as if once the file is loaded in a specific location it is constantly served to it and I can do jack shit about it.

Comment: Maybe it's something in the new Wordpress 4.5?